# Reopen question about DSLR video rail systems

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

The question [What is a "rail system"? What about rods?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57648/what-are-rods-rails-for) was closed as a duplicate of [What is a focusing rail?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/719/what-is-a-focusing-rail). Since the former is about rail systems used to mount additional equipment (e.g. pull focus system, matte box, monitor, etc.) used in video shooting and the latter is about focusing rails used in macrophotography, the former is definitely not a duplicate of the latter and should not have been closed as such. Please join me in voting to reopen.

Comment: OTOH, video questions are also off-topic.

Comment: JoanneC: That's a good point, and *off topic* would be at least a better reason to close. I don't think this is really a video question so much as an equipment question -- OP seems to be wondering how a rail system is useful in still photography.

Comment: I don't see the point of voting to reopen when it should ultimately be closed as off topic anyways from what I gather.

Comment: @dpollitt B Shaw's comment after my answer is a great example of why it should be reopened. Shaw explains how s/he uses a rail system for time lapse work. That comment would make a great answer and might inspire creative new uses of such equipment. Also, as rail systems are used more with DSLRs, the question is likely to keep coming up.

Comment: @Caleb - I know almost nothing about rails or rods so I was of the assumption that this knowledge was not beneficial to still photography, since it clearly can be - as B Shaw and you have described, then yes it probably should be reopened. Thanks for the explanation.